OpenSearch Anomaly Detector Missing Real-Time Anomalies Despite Successful Historical Detection
We created an anomaly detector using OpenSearch with a 10-minute window interval, focusing on three features: total_count, logstats, and flowstats, using sum aggregation and a shingle size of 8.
To test the detector, we inserted an anomaly with values of 6 million, while the usual values are around 6700. However, the detector failed to detect this anomaly in real-time data, even though it successfully identifies anomalies in historical data.
Our dataset contains hundreds of features, but the detector only considers these three. Why is the detector missing real-time anomalies, and how can we fix this?
We tried inserting the data multiple times and reviewing the logs but nothing seemed out of the ordinary.

Hello, could you be more precise on features' configuration?  What field types are they dealing with and what kind of data (why sum instead of e.g. avg)?
